# No me deja agregar un dato a un Array de objetos en C#

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy practicando C# y en un objeto API no me deja agregar un nuevo dato al array

> error CS0021: No se puede aplicar la indización con [] a una expresión del tipo 'Array'

```
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private Array people = new object[] {
       new Person { id=1, Name="Ana", age=24 },
       new Person { id=2, Name="Joseph", age=20 } 
    };

    [HttpGet("users")]

    public ActionResult<Person> GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(
            this.people
        );
    }

    [HttpGet("users/{id}")]

    public ActionResult<Person> Get(int id)
    {
        var pipe = new searchClient();
        var data = this.people;
        var looking = pipe.getClient(id, data);

        return Ok(
            looking
        );
    }

    [HttpPost("add_user")]

    public void AddClient(Object data)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < this.people.GetLength(0); x++) {
            this.people[x] = data; // Error
        }
    }

}
```

Estoy aprendiendo C#, no entiendo que me falta

Comment: utiliza arraylist y no vas a tener ese problema

Comment: [Acá](https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/c%23/no-se-puede-aplicar-la-indexacion-con-una-expresion-de-tipo-system.array-con-c/1045675234/) te explican el error que te sale y la solución al mismo :D

Comment: @jtaborga no se debe usar ArrayList. Microsoft desaconseja su uso desde hace ya muchos años.

Comment: Como bien te enlace Paulo, no uses `Array`, y ya que estamos tampoco lo definas como `object`. La definicion correcta debe ser algo como `private Person[] people = new Person[]...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa:

```
Array people = new object[5];
people.SetValue(data, x);
```

Aunque deberías optar por List y usarlo así:

```
List<string> people = new List<string>();
people.Add(obj);
people[0] = obj;
```

Comment: Dejame probarlo y te digo