# Hacer una API POST en .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Estoy tratando de hacer una API de tipo POST en .NET. Pero cuando lo pruebo en POSTMAN, no me regresa ningun codigo de respuesta, soy nuevo en .NET y c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace firstangular.Controllers

{
    [ApiController]

    // Api

    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private Person[] people = new Person[] {
           new Person { id=1, Name="Ana", age=24 },
           new Person { id=2, Name="Joseph", age=20 } 
        };

[HttpGet("users")]

    public ActionResult<Person> GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(
            this.people
        );
    }

[HttpPost("add_user")]

    public IActionResult AddClient(Person data)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < this.people.GetLength(0); x++) {
            this.people[x] = data;
        }
        return Ok()
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora que me doy cuenta con los GET no funcionan en POSTMAN, pero en el navegador si puedo ver los datos normales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el navegador, las APIS GET me las muestras sin ningun problema, el problema es que postman no me agarra con esas APIS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Http siempre espera una respuesta correspondiente a la comunicacion en este caso aunque tu metodo no retorne respuesta puedes regresar un ok para la respuesta. cambia void por IActionResult    y retorna ok.

Comment: Me sigue saliendo lo mismo

Comment: prueba con un get osea HttpGet IActionResult  retornando people.List() si te arroja un resultado

Comment: Oye ahora que lo veo, los get tampoco se muestran en postman, pero en el navegador si se muestran los get

Comment: @JOSEHERRADA puedes colocar la url que tienes en el navegador? es el mismo que estan en postman?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No me deja agregar un dato a un Array de objetos en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/449511/no-me-deja-agregar-un-dato-a-un-array-de-objetos-en-c)

Comment: Si, es la misma direccion IP que sale en el postman. Tal cual. Adjuntare una imagen

Comment: Esa pregunta es un problema de matrices en C#. Aqui es un problema de APIS, son diferentes @ger

Comment: creo que deberias revisar la configuración del https del postman, por defecto el controla el certificado y como es un self-signed certificate el que usa dotnet entonces lo bloquea. En Settings desactiva SSL Verification y prueba de vuelta. Igual veo que tus urls están mal, asi que espero que te devuelva un 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

el GET posiblemente no funcione en postman porque la uri termina con un slash y en el navegador no.
Respecto al POST, en la firma del método. Puntualmente en el parámetro Person no indicas que este valor viaja en el body de la petición.

public IActionResult AddClient([frombody]Person data)